# Regex validation with address house number mandatory

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex for address validation right now

```
^[a-z-A-Z\ \d\#\-\.\`\\\/\'\(\)]+$
```

Now I need to make sure the address has mandatory house number
I changed to:

```
^[\d*a-z-A-Z\ \d\#\-\.\`\\\/\'\(\)]+$
```

but it's not working.

I need to check against this address:
**8952 West Auburn St**

Comment: I think that would be helpful what format of address you're trying to parse, what kind of results you'd like to get and what you're getting with your experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a number, followed by any of these `[a-z-A-Z\ \d#-.\/'()]`, this is what you are looking for
`^\d{1}[a-z-A-Z\ \d#-.\/'()]+$`

It mean, it starts with a digit, with a length of at least 1, then matches anything in the square brackets, as many characters if you want

You can see it in action (and test alternatives) here:
https://regex101.com/r/tehNbZ/1